# what is the best source to find tenses of verbs

Tags: verbs

If I don't know/remember the past tense of a verb, I google for it. Often the returned searches are not  indicative. I just looked for the past tense of *seek*, and it took me 2 minutes to figure out that it was *sought*. What online sources  do you use to find tenses of verbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seek).

Answer (score 3):

I like [Verbix](http://www.verbix.com/languages) because it is multilingual and gives you full conjugations.

Comment: wiktionary is multilingual as well