# What is the antonym of the verb "equip"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

I know some words like *unclothe* and *disrobe* but these verbs refer to taking *clothes off*, I'm looking for a more accurate verb antonym of the verb **equip**, meaning *taking weapons off*.

**More Context**

In a video game, imagine  you **equip** your agent with [firearms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firearm) and send him/her for a duel, after fight finished, her/his weapon may run out of bullets and will be automatically **______**.
I need to inform the gamer that his/her agent is **______** and needs to be  *equipped* again before any other gamer attacks you.

Comment: If you are talking about weapons, the verb _disarm_ is often used to mean "remove weapons from [someone else]." If the person is taking off his or her own weapon, you might say "removing [one's] knife/pistol/whatever and putting it down [somewhere]."

Comment: @SvenYargs the Remove verb causes doubt that is it removed entirely from inventories (needs to buy it again) or only unequipped (only needs to equip it again after the weapon cooled down)

Comment: I'll note that a more specific word than **equip** for referring specifically to equipping a *weapon* would be **wield**. So an antonym for **wield** might be a suitable answer to this question as well.

Comment: [Holster and Unholster](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46802/63734) comes to mind.

Comment: @DanHenderson I feel like **wielding** a weapon is what you do after you have **equipped** it :)

Comment: Based on the large number of responses that all seem perfectly valid, I'm going to need to know the context; I know personally I would never say "equip" outside of a video game context.

Comment: *Dequip*, obviously.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you all for your kind help. I've added more details about the situation. Hope it clears the right answer

Comment: You can't make such a radical edit like that. It practically invalidates SomethingDark's answer. Now your question contains the word "unequipped", any visitor who sees that question and *then* reads the top (and accepted) answer is going to ask themself, why did that user repeat the same word used in OP. A similar edit *should have been done* much earlier on, because it gives CONTEXT and helps users provide the answer you *need*. Please replace the term **unequipped** with a blank space e.g. **....run out of bullets and will be automatically _______. I need to...**

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, you are perfectly right.

Comment: Why does this even need to be said? If you run out of bullets, your gun doesn't disappear from your hand, does it? In this duel, if you start with 10 bullets, and use 9, you remain equipped, right? If you use 10 bullets does the God Of The Game remove it from you? Why? If this routinely happens (that a gun is wrenched from your hands when it runs out of ammo) then you hardly need to state it at this particular point.

Comment: @NickGammon I need to inform the gamer in logs list. Besides, I am developer and this is the designer's decision to make :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Video games usually say **unequip**.

> [unequip](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unequip) (v) - 1. To remove equipment. 2. (video games) In role-playing video games, to deactivate an item being carried by a player.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen its usage as an adjective, but does it work as verb too? isn't it bad formed?

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah - it definitely works as a verb as well, I just can't find a good source other than "I'm a native English speaker."

Comment: +1. No dictionary hits for **unequip**, but it would be recognised by the majority of native English speakers, *especially* gamers of any kind.

Comment: Weapons can also be "unwield" since you "wield" weapons. Armour you usually "wear" and "remove"

Comment: In a gaming context I always simply used "remove". It clearly makes sense for items that would be equipped by being worn, and worked well enough for weapons that might be in different places (in hand, on back, in holster, etc.) depending on state of use too.

Comment: Aren't we supposed to downvote made-up words? Why is this both the most popular and the accepted answer?

Comment: @talrnu The link in the answer lists "unequipped", if not "unequip". Surely one implies the other.

Comment: @talrnu "made-up words" means words that the answerer made up.

Comment: @talrnu: English in comparison to German sparsely forms new words, but `un-` is a common prefix. I'd hesitate to call the result "made up" if it follows common language rules. Another example in this grey area is the result of verbing nouns.

Comment: This normally applies to the person, not the equipment. A typical usage such as 'Bob was unequipped for the trip as he lacked a life jacket' does not mean someone put Bob in the cupboard.

Comment: I say "made up" to say "not defined in a popular reference". There is no verb "unequip" so defined, so technically yes, this answer is made up. I'm with JEL in that there ought not be any hard and fast rules for things like this, I'm just marveling at how often I see decent or even good responses to a question downvoted on this site because they are "made up", i.e. they aren't backed up by good references or data, making them "bad answers".

Comment: @JEL - I was under the impression that Wiktionary references were frowned upon, but if I am mistaken I'll gladly add your link to the answer.

Comment: @SomethingDark, see [What is the best source...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/what-is-the-best-source-to-find-tenses-of-verbs/7603#7603). I'm sure you can find multiple people here to disdain any external reference, but my own take is that *all* external references are "for what it's worth" and "buyer beware".

Comment: @talrnu - This is more than just a made-up word, it appears to be a [commonly-used word](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+unequip+the%22) in this context. That probably explains the high number of upvotes.

Answer (score 19):

**Disarm**

> verb (used with object)
>
> to deprive of a weapon or weapons.
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> to lay down one's weapons.

Comment: Note that disarm can and often will be used to mean removing the equipment from someone else. *"She disarmed him."*

Comment: Based on OP's description of "taking weapons off" I think that **Disarm** is the most appropriate. *Before entering through the security checkpoint, the [Hitman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman_%28video_game_series%29) disarmed himself.*

Answer (score 7):

If the weapon currently being equipped is being returned to a holder that the individual is wearing, then depending on the weapon type we have a few choices:

- If it's a firearm you would **holster** it.
- If it's a blade, then you'd **sheathe** it.

If you're putting it into a more general storage location, such as a backpack, then you could be said to **stow** it.

If you're simply dropping it to the ground, well, I'd say **drop** is as good a word as any.

Comment: Holster and sheathe would be the opposite of 'draw', not equip. You would need to have the weapon equipped to do any of those things.

Answer (score 6):

Consider, ***unarm***

> To divest of armor or arms; disarm.

[American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unarm)

Answer (score 3):

Although rare, 'disequip' is a good transitive and intransitive verb with the meaning you intend:

> **diseˈquip**, *v.*
>   *rare.*
>   *trans.* To divest (any one) of his equipment; *intr.* (for *refl.*) to doff one's equipment.
>   1831   F. A. Kemble *Jrnl. in Rec. Girlhood* (1878) III. 23   [He] arrived just as we had disequipped.

["diseˈquip, v.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/54283?rskey=BNKRlP&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed January 07, 2016).]

This verb is admirably suited for a 'disrarity' upon frequent use by gamers.

### Some 'Dis'ambiguation and Other Notes in Response to OP Edits, Etc.

I used 'dis'ambiguation rather than 'un'ambiguation in the heading because I'm, most precisely, taking the ambiguity away rather than negating it. That's the difference between 'dis-' and 'un-'.

1. If by "more accurate" you mean 'more commonly used in a given context', then 'disequip' might not the word for you; in the language of gamers, 'unequip' is by far the most commonly used word for the sense you describe, at least for the time being.
2. If by "more accurate" you mean 'better suited to and more expressive of the concept intended', then 'disequip' might be the most accurate word to use, or perhaps 'deactivate', as shown next.

A commonly used verb, and accurate for the sense I understand you to intend, is 'deactivate':

> *trans.* To render inactive ....

(op. cit.)

Comment: I'd argue that 'good' and 'rare' here are not totally compatible.

Comment: Which is the more correct form: unequip as @somethingdark said or disequip as you said?

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah As a native english speaker, I unequip relatively frequently. I have never heard disequip. I would use unequip.

Comment: @alihaghighatkhah, as an expert on the uses and abuses of English words, I know that 'unequip' is the wrong form. That prefix, 'un-' doesn't carry the meaning you describe. The prefix 'dis-' does. Why use an inept contrived word when an existing apt word will do?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I wouldn't argue that.

Comment: @JEL It's generally a good idea to use an "inept contrived" word over an existing apt word when it's far more commonly used and understood. Just because disequip technically exists and dis- is technically a better suited prefix doesn't mean you should use it, because that's now how language works. Disequip gives 1 600 hits on google, unequip gives 376 000. Seems like disequip will be a pretty ostentatious choice in this case.

Comment: @Tobberoth, you've mastered the 374,400 flies argument, but I don't agree. No matter how many people use the wrong word, it's still the wrong word. Meaning, and language, is not the democracy you'd like it to be. As for what word the OP should use, surely you should leave that decision to the OP?

Comment: @JEL Meaning and language is exactly a "democracy" as you aptly put it. This is why there are exceptions in languages. As much as linguists love to put clear rules and perfectly define meanings, it's completely unrealistic because languages evolve with no concern of their efforts. If everyone today decided that "duck" from now on means "fish", that's what it will mean, etymology be damned. Take the word "awful" which used to mean "full of awe" in a positive sense, are you going to claim people who use awful in a negative sense are using the wrong word? Of course not.

Comment: @Tobberoth, of course language is not a democracy, no matter how you want to redefine democracy. The OP asked for a "more accurate" verb, not the commonly used one which, as it happens, is inaccurate, clumsy and misleading. I have a perverse habit of answering the question asked, not the one other people wish had been asked.

Answer (score 2):

**Strip** works too. You can strip someone of a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If there was an antonym, it would be "strip"

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer unless you elaborate.

Comment: It also looks very much like Lightness Races in Orbit's 2016 answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, it is and I don't know how I missed that. Any and all credit goes to Lightness Races in Orbit.

Comment: @fev Sorry but this instance really is that simple. What research on "equip" and "strip" makes you doubt they're antonymous?

Answer (score -3):

Pillaged, looted, stripped.  There could be degrees of lack.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer was flagged for its length and content. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Please don't give multiple options without giving a way for the asker to discern between them.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it's a real word, but "dequip" comes to mind...

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer. There are two reasons. 1. The answer states that *dequip* might not be a commonly understood word. 2. The answer doesn't explain anything about how to use the word. Given 1. that makes 2. very important. 1. is bad because the answer should address the question for people who don't know the answer and this answer implies that the word shouldn't be used, because *dequip* might not be a word people know, while also implying that the word should be used because it is posted as an answer.